# Subbases and half-planes

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, it's easy to show that $H(x,y)=\{w\in X\mid d(x,w)>d(y,w)\}$ is open in the topology $\tau$ induced by $d$. Is, in general, $\{H(x,y)\mid (x,y)\in X\times X, x\neq y\}$ a subbasis for the topology induced on $X$ by $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take $(X,d)=\ell^2$ endowed with the standard metric.